# Check if numpy array is masked or not

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an easy way to check if numpy array is masked or not?

Currently, I do the following to check if `marr` is masked or not:

```
try:
   arr = marr.data
except:
   arr = marr
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the python function `isinstance` to check if an object is an instance of a class.

```
>>> isinstance(np.ma.array(np.arange(10)),np.ma.MaskedArray)
True
>>> isinstance(np.arange(10),np.ma.MaskedArray)
False
```